# Flutter - DatePicker is not opening if it is same date(today)

Tags: android, flutter, datetimepicker

I want to enable only Friday from week in my Calendar. It is working if it is not same date i.e. If current day is not friday then it is working, else if I am trying to open the Calendar on Friday, then I am getting below exception.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker.dart': Failed assertion: line 1147 pos 5: 'selectableDayPredicate == null || selectableDayPredicate(initialDate)': Provided initialDate must satisfy provided selectableDayPredicate
```

Below are my code I am using.

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

    bool defineSelectable(DateTime val) {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      // disabled all days before today
      if (val.isBefore(now)) {
        return false;
      }
      // disabled all days except Friday
      switch (val.weekday) {
        case DateTime.friday:
          return true;
          break;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }

    int daysToAdd(int todayIndex, int targetIndex) {
      print('todayIndex $todayIndex');
      print('targetIndex $targetIndex');
      if (todayIndex < targetIndex) { // jump to target day in same week
        return targetIndex - todayIndex;
      } else if (todayIndex > targetIndex) { // must jump to next week
        return 7 + targetIndex - todayIndex;
      } else {
        return 0; // date is matched
      }
    }

    DateTime defineInitialDate() {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      int dayOffset = daysToAdd(now.weekday, DateTime.friday);
      print('dayOffset: $dayOffset');
      return now.add(Duration(days: dayOffset));
    }

    Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
      print('defineInitialDate: ${defineInitialDate()}');
      print('defineSelectable: $defineSelectable');
      final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: defineInitialDate(),
          selectableDayPredicate: defineSelectable,
          firstDate: DateTime(2018, 12),
          lastDate: DateTime(2020, 12));
      if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) selectedDate = picked;
      var formatter = DateFormat('EEEE, dd-MMMM-yyyy');
      String formatted = formatter.format(selectedDate);
      print('Select Date: $formatted');
      _askGiveProvider.meetingSink(formatted);
      //addEventBloc.eventDateSink(formatted);
    }
```

Not sure what exactly is problem. It would be great if you can tell me what I need to update to get this.

And also I want to enable only 2 weeks from current date. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution
You need to make defineSelectable function return true on initialDate you are passing. See the working code below

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime initialData;

bool defineSelectable(DateTime val) {
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
//make it return true on initialDate
if(val.compareTo(initialData)==0){
return true;
}
// disabled all days before today
if (val.isBefore(now)) {
return false;
}
// disabled all days except Friday
switch (val.weekday) {
case DateTime.friday:
  return true;
  break;
default:
  return false;
}
}

int daysToAdd(int todayIndex, int targetIndex) {
print('todayIndex $todayIndex');
print('targetIndex $targetIndex');
if (todayIndex < targetIndex) { // jump to target day in same 
week
return targetIndex - todayIndex;
} else if (todayIndex > targetIndex) { // must jump to next 
week
return 7 + targetIndex - todayIndex;
} else {
return 0; // date is matched
}
}

DateTime defineInitialDate() {
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
int dayOffset = daysToAdd(now.weekday, DateTime.friday);
print('dayOffset: $dayOffset');
return now.add(Duration(days: dayOffset));
}

Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
initialData = defineInitialDate();
print('defineInitialDate: ${initialData}');
print('defineSelectable: $defineSelectable');
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: initialData,
  selectableDayPredicate: defineSelectable,
  firstDate: DateTime(2018, 12),
  lastDate: DateTime(2020, 12));
if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) selectedDate = 
picked;
//var formatter = DateFormat('EEEE, dd-MMMM-yyyy');
//String formatted = formatter.format(selectedDate);
print('Select Date: $selectedDate');
//_askGiveProvider.meetingSink(formatted);
//addEventBloc.eventDateSink(formatted);
}
```

Comment: Great Thanks Brijesh, You are correct. Also can you help me with this 'enable only 2 weeks from current date'.

Comment: @vikaspandey Please accept the answer as correct.
For that you can write simple condition for checking the difference of days between current date & parameter date is >14(2 weeks) then return false in defineSelectable method.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. Let me try that.

Answer (score 3):

try this,
this will not disable today's date after changing date

```
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime initialData;

  bool defineSelectable(DateTime val) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    // disabled all days except Friday
    switch (val.weekday) {
      case DateTime.friday:
        return true;
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

  }

  int daysToAdd(int todayIndex, int targetIndex) {
    print('todayIndex $todayIndex');
    print('targetIndex $targetIndex');
    if (todayIndex < targetIndex) { // jump to target day in same week
      return targetIndex - todayIndex ;
    } else if (todayIndex > targetIndex) { // must jump to next week
      return 7 + targetIndex - todayIndex ;
    } else {
      return 0; // date is matched
    }
  }

  DateTime defineInitialDate() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    int dayOffset = daysToAdd(now.weekday, DateTime.friday);
    print('dayOffset: $dayOffset');
    return now.add(Duration(days: dayOffset));
  }

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    initialData = defineInitialDate();
    print('defineInitialDate: ${defineInitialDate()}');
    print('defineSelectable: $defineSelectable');
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initialData,
        selectableDayPredicate: defineSelectable,
        firstDate: DateTime(2018, 12),
        lastDate: DateTime(defineInitialDate().year,defineInitialDate().month, defineInitialDate().day+14));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) selectedDate = picked;
    var formatter = DateFormat('EEEE, dd-MMMM-yyyy');
    String formatted = formatter.format(selectedDate);
    print('Select Date: $formatted');
//    _askGiveProvider.meetingSink(formatted);
    //addEventBloc.eventDateSink(formatted);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, same as this. Thanks.